# How to populate a list of links assigned to macros

Tags: ms-access

I have a main form (in a single form view) that show a record from a table. I am going to add a sub form (probably a continuous form view) which can show a list of fields (probably a name) from all records from a child table that match condition PrimaryKey = ForeignKey.

What is the best way to make the list of the fields sort of clickable so that I can click on any of them and e.g. open a form with information about a child record? Should I look for hyperlinks in reports, a list box, a continuous sub form with records?

What would you suggest?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have been suggested the solution to my problem on different forum and I think it works and will perfectly match my requirements.

http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?p=1219604#post1219604

Comment: Link-only answers are usually not good: can you give details?

Comment: Hi. I am sorry I cannot do it now. It's an over 1 year old problem and it was rather situational. I am not dealing with this at the moment. I'll try to put some details but later. I cannot promise anything atm.